# 'Template is missing' error in Rails 3.1 when trying to render

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rendering, partial-views, missing-template

I'm trying to use Ajax with my CRUD.  I'm following this [tutorial](http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

I see this error:

```
Missing template posts/edit, application/edit with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/Users/wangstabill/Code/rails/ajax_on_rails/app/views"
```

when I try to click the edit link.  It looks like:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post, remote: true) %>
```

Now, I have a simple js.erb file located in app/views/posts/edit.js.erb.  This file is not used for a response.  Looking at the above error message, the :formats key's value is the array that only contains :html.  If I create a edit.html.js, this works fine but not the edit.js.erb file.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101822/error-in-rails-3-1-using-js-jquery-template-is-missing) recommends removing the old rails.js file, but I'm quite sure I never included it in this simple app (or where to find it if I did).

Here's what my controller class looks like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :load, :except => [:destroy, :create]

    def load
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def index
        @post  = Post.new
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(params[:post])
        if @post.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully created.'
            load
        end
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
            flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully updated.'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'Successfully destroyed post.'
        load
    end
end
```

I don't understand why my create and destroy actions are successfully responding with js.erb templates, but not edit.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `remote` option should be an option for `link_to`, not for `edit_post_path`. Try moving it outside the parentheses:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), remote: true %>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for you're help Dylan.  This solves the issue.  You can check out the code at [my github](https://github.com/wangstabill/100--Ajax-CRUD--Rails-3.1)!  Thank you!

Comment: Cool! Make sure to accept an answer if it helps you, otherwise people won't bother spending time answering your questions in the future.